# Explanation for If statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

There are several questions about the if statement on this forum. I tried the suggestions but the code produced the same error each time. Here is a description of what the code should do:

- Create a new column (Efficiency) in an existing dataframe (file)
- Populate Efficiency column based on values from an existing column (Duration)

I created the following code:

```
file$Efficiency<-if(file$Duration <= 5) {"Above Par"} else
{if(file$Duration > 5 & file$Duration <= 15) {"Par"} else
{if(file$Duration > 15 & file$Duration <= 30) {"Below Par"} else
{"Unacceptable"}}}
```

I get the following warning

```
Warning message:
In if (file$Duration <= 5) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

It is mentioned in several posts that if statement takes one value and haven't accepted that as an explanation of what I see. If the statement is true then I wonder what is the use of the else function.

Comment: Are you looking for `cut()` ?

Comment: Did none of those posts mention the need to use `ifelse` when processing vectors?????????

Comment: @jogo: I haven't heard of cut before. Would you expand on it.

Comment: you are using the if statement incorrectly

Comment: @42: If else satisfies one condition and my attempt is to search for varying times and assign a efficiency level accordingly.

Comment: `file$Duration` is a vector, some of its elements may fulfill the condition, others not. This ambiguity leads to the warning that only the first element is considered. By using `ifelse`, instead you have the possibility to define an action for each vector element in `file$Duration` depending on whether it fulfills the condition or not.

Comment: if else has not worked for my needs, hence the need to post this question.

Comment: Sigh. `if(){}else{}` is NOT the same as `ifelse`. Please type `?ifelse` at your console prompt. Then type `?'if'` at the console prompt and note the extreme differences in these two functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file$Efficiency <- cut(file$Duration, breaks=c(-1,5,15,30,200), labels=c("Above Par", "Par", "Below Par", "Unacceptable"))
```

Here is a little example of data from me:

```
x <- c(0,1, 4:6, 14:16, 29:31)
y <- cut(x, breaks=c(-1,5,15,30,200), labels=c("Above Par", "Par", "Below Par", "Unacceptable"))
data.frame(x=x, y=y)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I hadn't seen this before and I appreciate you sharing this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized solution with two `ifelse` statements:

```
file <- data.frame(Duration=c(1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,7))
d <- ifelse (file$Duration > 3, "medium", "short")
d <- ifelse (file$Duration > 6, "long", d)
> d
#[1] "short"  "short"  "short"  "medium" "short"  "medium" "medium" "medium" "long"
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. This makes better sense and helps in accepting some of the other previous comments (as in complete as they were) to consider ifelse!

Comment: @sfyn Glad I could help. You may want to look into the subject of logical subsetting. It is often more concise and, in my opinion, clearer than `ifelse` statements. For example, the third line in the code above could simply be `d[file$Duration > 6] <- "long"`.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you had a dataframe with a column named Duration

```
 a = data.frame(Duration=c(1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,7))
```

define a function that returns an efficiency value according to duration:

```
eff <- function(duration){
    if (duration<5) return('bad')
    else return('good')}
```

create a new column for the dataframe

```
a[, 'Efficiency'] <- sapply(a$Duration, eff)
```

Done

Comment: thank you for posting this example but it does separation by two levels, not 4 as I need it to be.

Comment: of course it is an example, the idea is that you learn. With this example you can define more complex ways to assign the levels, with cut you are restricted to intervals.